# How to convert Dictionaries in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary like below and I want to to convert

`Dictionary<List<String>,Object>`

to

`Dictionary<String,Object>`

Comment: Convert... how? Like every item of the list to be mapped to the same object? Are you sure all lists have unique strings? You could just do it manually with a `foreach`, or maybe with some Linq. Have you tried anything so far? Is this [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)? If not, I recommend you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Andrew yes, I want every item of the list to be mapped to same object. Each list has unique strings. No this is not homework.

Comment: *Each list has unique strings* - does it mean "the strings in the lists are guaranteed to be globally unique" ? Strings may be unique within their own list but if two different lists hold the same string you'll struggle.

Comment: As an aside, why `object` as a value? It can hold anything, sure, but using it may point to there being a data modelling problem elsewhere

Comment: Can you supply sample data to show what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish the mapping as clarified in the question's comments like this:

```
Dictionary<List<String>, Object> original = new Dictionary<List<string>, object>()
{
    { new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" }, 42 }
};

var mapped = original
    .SelectMany(kv => kv.Key, (val, key) => new { Key = key, val.Value})
    .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);
```

Result:

```
Key Value
A   42
B   42
C   42
```

> Each list has unique strings.

If *any* string is duplicated in *any* list, you'll get a `DuplicateKeyException`.